# Is it okay for me to Overclock?

Tags: windows, overclocking, hardware-acceleration

I've checked my CPU and Motherboard and I was told their all okay to overclock. I'm a bit worried about my temperature as its currently sitting at around 40 - 50c at 20% CPU usage.

Am I okay to overclock?
[image: https://i.imgur.com/jlAHQmH.png]

Comment: You're fine til the magic smoke escapes... not that you're ever going to gain much on that machine. low-end is low-end. Accept it for what it is & prolong its life.

Comment: No, your CPU is not unlocked for overclocking, so you cannot overclock.

Comment: Only the Intel CPUs with a "K" in their model number can be overclocked.

Comment: If my answer was useful to you, please accept it if you feel appropriate. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**You can't overclock your CPU** because your CPU *isn't* unlocked.

My daily-basis PC is basically your PC and it works just fine. I only get 50C when playing some games / heavy tasks (I have a custom-case too, when I had a small-form case I had temperatures like yours just *browsing the web*)

But your actual temperatures are ***safe-ish***, but you can change the CPU thermal paste / clean your system and probably temperatures will decrease a little.

Even if you **could overclock** you probably **won't** notice the difference since the i3-2120 is a dual-core CPU (and dual-cores CPU's are getting deprecated).